# Getting the error expected resource of type attr

Tags: android, lockscreen, home-button

I am trying to use the Home Key Locker https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker 
I want to be able to detect and prevent homescreen button click on the lock screen. Majority of the answers mentioned that it cannot be disabled.

This is the HomeKeyLocker Class :

```
 package com.example.harshilshah.screenonoff;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.AlertDialog;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Gravity;
  import android.view.MotionEvent;
  import android.view.WindowManager;
  import android.widget.FrameLayout;

  import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
  import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED;
  import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;


public class HomeKeyLocker {
private OverlayDialog mOverlayDialog;

public void lock(Activity activity) {
    if (mOverlayDialog == null) {
        mOverlayDialog = new OverlayDialog(activity);
        mOverlayDialog.show();
    }
}

public void unlock() {
    if (mOverlayDialog != null) {
        mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
        mOverlayDialog = null;
    }
}

  public static class OverlayDialog extends AlertDialog {

    public OverlayDialog(Activity activity) {
        super(activity, R.style.OverlayDialog);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.type = TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
        params.dimAmount = 0.0F; // transparent
        params.width = 0;
        params.height = 0;
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        getWindow().setFlags(FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, 0xffffff);
        setOwnerActivity(activity);
        setCancelable(false);
    }

    public final boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionevent) {
        return true;
    }

    protected final void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(getContext());
        framelayout.setBackgroundColor(0);
        setContentView(framelayout);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the styles.xml

```
 <resources>

 <!-- Base application theme. -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>

<style name="OverlayDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I am getting an error Expected resource of type Attr in the following lines

```
 public OverlayDialog(Activity activity) {
        super(activity, R.style.OverlayDialog);//ERROR
```

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. What caused it for me was that I imported the `android.R class`, instead of the `R` class already defined in my app. So it wasn't using the **styles.xml** defined in my app's values, where the OverlayDialog was implemented, but the standard one defined in the Android system that obviously didn't have it. Once I deleted `import android.R` and added `import com.example.myapp.R` it worked just fine.